# Clio key card only working manually after battery change

Tags: smartkey

I’ve just changed the key card battery and now the car will only lock/unlock with pressing buttons and start on with key card in slot. It’s also playing up as sometimes I’ll have to press button more than once. Before change car would lock itself as I moved away, unlock as I pressed door handle and start without key card in slot. What’s going on? Is there a way to reset it back?
Thank you